# Segments of large TCP Packet are lost during communication

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I am working on applications that communicate through the TCP channel through windivert library. It is working fine for small packets but in case of large TCP packets i.e. over 10000 bytes, segments are lost during transmission.
Following is the scenario:

- 11086 bytes of data split into 20 segments of 536 bytes
- I receive random packets i.e. sometimes 18 or 19 and sometimes all
  packets
- In case of loss packets, DUP ACK is sent or retransmission occurs
- Sometimes packets arrived in out of order
- For each packet which application receives, ACK is sent out

Is this due to ACK timeout issue or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Windivert does not try to preserve packet order. As the documentation says:

> *WinDivert can cause packets to be out-of-order*:
> Simply running the `passthru.exe` sample program can cause
> packets to become out-of-order.
> This is not a bug, since there is no requirement for packets to
> remain in-order.
> However, this may affect other buggy software
> (e.g. some buggy NAT implementations)
> that incorrectly assume packets to be in-order.

If you're filtering lots of packets in user space, that can also cause packets to be lost. As the documentation says:

> Packets/events are not queued indefinitely, and if not handled in a timely
> manner, data may be lost. The amount of time a packet/event is queued can be controlled using the *WinDivertSetParam()* function.

You don't describe any serious consequences or specific problems, so I would say everything you're describing is probably normal.

One last thing, there's no such thing as a "large TCP packet". You are just talking about cases where there's a lot of data to send or a large number of TCP packets received at about the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I am not getting my payload delivered fully on application end. There is no traffic on the network. I've analyzed the behavior through Wireshark and it is observed that some packets not delivered and some **ACK** are sent **DUPLICATE**.

Comment: @Hassan All the behavior you're seeing is normal, as I explained. However, I don't know what you mean by "getting my payload delivered fully". Can you describe in as much detail as you can the actual problem? Are you getting out the same stream of bytes you are sending or not?

Comment: I am not getting the same stream of bytes which I am sending to the application. Some segments are lost during transmission. The application receives messages from the device and parses the message according to some logic. I am testing a message which is delivered to the application in chunks and then all chunks are merged together when the FIN packet is received then we forward them to parsing. But in this case, since some packets are missing the final payload which is sent to parsing becomes faulty. I need to make sure that the FIN packet is received after all chunks.

Comment: @Hassan It's hard to understand what you're saying. What do you mean by the payload "becomes faulty"? Are bytes missing? Duplicated? Out of order in the data stream? None of those things should be possible and, if they are, something is going on way above and beyond things like duplicate acks or packets being lost or out of order.

Comment: Are bytes missing? **yes**.  Duplicated? **sometime**. Out of order in the data stream? **Sometimes**. What I mean by this is that the payload which I sent is not received. Received payload has missing bytes

Comment: what I mean by faulty is that if I sent **ABCDE** then I receive **ABE**. **CD** are missing.

Comment: @Hassan Bytes missing from the received data stream should never happen. Are you 100% sure that's what's happening. For example, you may be expecting A, B, C, D, E and receive A, BCD, E and think you didn't get C and D because you didn't notice them stuck onto the end of B.

Comment: yes I am receiving missing bytes (segments) from the data stream. Each segment that I received is of same length so none of the packets are merged with other and I am also logging the packet data when the stream of data is received. There is no data which is appended in other segments.